# Sorting Object On The Basis Of dayInNumber

Tags: java, android

Currently i am getting data from my list but i get the data randomly, if anyone can help me to sort data on the basis of **dayInNumber** i have attached the picture of my database. I want to sort the data like 1 2 3 4 .. 14 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82R1f.png)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `Client` class defined as

```
class Client {

    private long dayInNumber;
    private String clientName;
    private String day;

   //setters and getters ommitted for brevity and clarity
}
```

Then you have a list of clients

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
```

To sort that `dayInNumber` you can either sort that in SQL (`order by` clause) assuming the data is coming from SQLite.

Or you can create a custom `Comparator<T>` of `Client` objects to do the sorting in code as below

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ClientDayInNumberComparator implements Comparator<Client> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Client c1, Client c2) {
        if(c1.getDayInNumber() > c2.getDayInNumber()) return 1;
        else if(c1.getDayInNumber() < c2.getDayInNumber()) return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

This will sort clients by dayInNumber in ascending order (1, 2, 3,...N). Then use it as follows

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(clients, new ClientDayInNumberComparator());
```

`Collections` is packed in `java.utils` package which you'll need to import

Comment: Thank you for you time. after calling  clients = new ArrayList<>(); the contents or items present in my list become 0

Comment: @saadzahoor Obviously, You need to fill the list with proper data, your data! Which is out of the scope of this question...so, you can safely ignore that line

Answer (score 0):

for sorting lists we can use sort(your_list) method of Collections class. This will sort the list as per the natural ordering i.e. ascending order. Since you want it sorted on the basis of a particular feature you should implement Comparator interface with type safety same as of your list. You will have to implement compareTo method. Refer to the below code for FYR:- `

```
public class Temp implements Comparable<Temp> {
    Temp(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Temp t1 = new Temp(11,2);
        Temp t2 = new Temp(9,5);
        Temp t3 = new Temp(1,7);
        Temp t4 = new Temp(10,9);
        Temp t5 = new Temp(14,11);

        ArrayList<Temp> al = new ArrayList<Temp>();
        al.add(t1);
        al.add(t2);
        al.add(t3);
        al.add(t4);
        al.add(t5);
        Collections.sort(al);
        for(Temp i:al) {
            System.out.println(i.a+"," +i.b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Temp o) {
        if(a==o.a) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(a>o.a) {
            return 1;  
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}`
```